# Nested class property set in bootsrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have code block look like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Now I want to set form-control class width 30 % only for this block where .form-group > col-sm-10 > form-control. Thanks

Comment: like that demo??? - http://www.bootply.com/nqpaEbKX5R

Comment: Thanks @MaryMelody, but if i use only <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password"> without block sequence, There will be apply 30 % width. but that place no need to set width. the width will set only for block sequence .form-group > col-sm-10 > form-control.

Comment: please try this demo - http://www.bootply.com/QV0WYYIDTj

Comment: perhaps, you just forgot to add the `.` before the class names `.form-group > ?col-sm-10 > ?form-control` and it should be like this - `.form-group > .col-sm-10 > .form-control`

Comment: Hi @MaryMelody, Without media query this is not working into my project. I have used this .form-group > .col-sm-10 > .form-control. I do not know what is the relation of media.

Comment: by default bootstrap use `@media (min-width: 768px){.col-sm-10 {width: 83.33333333%;}}` (e.g 83.33%) for `.col-sm-10` and if you want to change the width to 30% then you need to use `@media` query as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61215/discussion-between-shohel-and-mary-melody).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

### Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/1luswabAdq)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="width = 30%">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-group > .col-sm-10 > .form-control {
        width: 30%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in-line coding if you wish to set the width to 30% only for this block of code.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="password" style="width:30%" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
</div>
</div>
```